# my C# windows application runs on system startup. but works in windows xp and not in windows 7. I have written these codes

Tags: c#

```
RegistryKey rkStartUp = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey StartupPath;
StartupPath =rkStartUp.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
if (StartupPath.GetValue("MyApplication") == null)
{
    StartupPath.SetValue("MyApplication", Application.ExecutablePath, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
}
else
{
    StartupPath.DeleteValue("MyApplication", true);
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, XP is 32-bit, and Win7 is 64-bit?

Comment: Your guess is wrong @Dennis, that particular key exists in 64-bit editions and it should work normally. He has no admin privileges.

Comment: @Kamil: the issue isn't in existence of registry key. He writes registry value to `Wow6432Node`, but Windows explorer on 64-bit system is... 64-bit, and it reads 64-bit registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be aware that registry keys are different for 32-bit and 64-bit systems. Also, in case your application is not running with admin rights, it is probably not permitted to write registry keys.